# Why does it print new client connected: network-2?

Tags: scala, sbt

Sometimes the `sbt` prints the following:

```
[info] new client connected: network-2
[info] new client connected: network-3
[info] new client connected: network-4
[info] new client connected: network-5
[info] new client connected: network-6
[info] new client connected: network-7
[info] new client connected: network-8
[info] new client connected: network-9
[info] new client connected: network-10
[info] new client connected: network-11
[info] new client connected: network-12
[info] new client connected: network-13
[info] new client connected: network-14
[info] new client connected: network-15
[info] new client connected: network-16
[info] new client connected: network-17
[info] new client connected: network-18
[info] new client connected: network-19
[info] new client connected: network-20
[info] new client connected: network-21
[info] new client connected: network-22
[info] new client connected: network-23
[info] new client connected: network-24
[info] new client connected: network-25
[info] new client connected: network-26
[info] new client connected: network-27
[info] new client connected: network-28
```

Why?

Comment: SBT is a server, other programs may connect to it, to trigger compilation and other tasks. Probably this is from your IDE.